# MySQL Dynamic query with declares

Tags: mysql, variables, declare

I would like to ask if it is possible to `DECLARE` variables in dynamic queries.

i.e.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `storedProcedureName`()
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    SET @i = 0;

    PREPARE dynamicQuery FROM 'DECLARE x INT(11);';
    EXECUTE dynamicQuery;

    PREPARE dynamicQuery FROM 'SET x := ?;';
    EXECUTE dynamicQuery USING @i;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamicQuery;

    /* More Queries Here */

END
```

But I'm getting syntax error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE x INT(11)' at line 1`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First - DECLARE is allowed only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement.
- Second - not all stataments can be used in PREPARE statement, more details here - [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

But you can use something like this -

```
SET @text = 'something';
SET @var = NULL;
SET @query = 'SELECT ? INTO @var';
PREPARE s FROM @query;
EXECUTE s USING @text;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

SELECT @var;
+-----------+
| @var      |
+-----------+
| something |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi @Devart, my `PREPARE` statement is actually inside a `stored procedure`. Edited my question. Thanks :D

Comment: Anyway, the DECLARE statement cannot be used in prepared statements. Try to use user variables (@var1, @var2,...).

Comment: I see, other statements are not yet supported. Thanks a lot. I guess I have no choice but to use `session variables`.